# PhoneStateListener Android bad values

Tags: android

I'm facing a problem on android. I would like to know if the device is connected to GSM network so it can send a sms.

I have tried two ways and it ends the same way.
On the Moto G 4G I am able to determine if it has an access.
On the Redmi Note 4 it always returns false.

The first one :

```
public static boolean hasCellularAccess(Context context) {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    if(telephonyManager == null || telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo() == null || telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().size() == 0){
        return false;
    }

    if (telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0) instanceof CellInfoLte){
        CellInfoLte cellInfoLte = (CellInfoLte)telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
        CellSignalStrength cellSignalStrengthGsm = cellInfoLte.getCellSignalStrength();
        return cellSignalStrengthGsm.getLevel() > 0;
    }

    CellInfoGsm cellinfogsm = (CellInfoGsm) telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
    CellSignalStrength cellSignalStrengthGsm = cellinfogsm.getCellSignalStrength();
    return cellSignalStrengthGsm.getLevel() > 0;
}
```

The second one:

```
public class CustomPhoneListener extends PhoneStateListener {
private static final String TAG = "PhoneListener";

@Override
public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
    super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
    Log.i(TAG, "onSignalStrengthsChanged: " + signalStrength);
    if (signalStrength.isGsm()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onSignalStrengthsChanged: getGsmSignalStrength "
                + signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() + signalStrength);
    }
    try {

        Method[] methods = android.telephony.SignalStrength.class
                .getMethods();
        for (Method mthd : methods) {
            if (mthd.getName().equals("getLteSignalStrength")) {
                Log.i(TAG,
                        "onSignalStrengthsChanged: " + mthd.getName() + " "
                                + mthd.invoke(signalStrength));
            }
        }
    } catch (SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}}
```

On the Redmi I have :

> SignalStrength: 0 48 -120 -160 -7 0 -1 **99** -93 -6 282 2147483647
>   gsm|lte 1 1 1
>
> ==> value 99 is unknown

On the Moto :

> SignalStrength: 99 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 **18** -109 -8 116
>   2147483647 2147483647 gsm|lte 0 -108 -1 false 0 0 0 0 2 99 99 99 4
>
> ==> value between 0 and 31 is ok

Anyone faced the problem before and resolved it ?
I have read that the problem exists also on some Samsung Galaxy.

Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works !

So here is my final work, it works. It seems that the API returns bad value if the phone has a big uptime value.

```
public static boolean hasCellularAccess(Context context) {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if(telephonyManager == null || telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo() == null || telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().size() == 0){
        return false;
    }

    if (telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0) instanceof CellInfoLte){
        CellInfoLte cellInfoLte = (CellInfoLte)telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
        CellSignalStrength cellSignalStrengthGsm = cellInfoLte.getCellSignalStrength();
        return cellSignalStrengthGsm.getLevel() > 0;
    }

    if(telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0) instanceof CellInfoGsm){
        CellInfoGsm cellinfogsm = (CellInfoGsm) telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
        CellSignalStrength cellSignalStrengthGsm = cellinfogsm.getCellSignalStrength();
        return cellSignalStrengthGsm.getLevel() > 0;
    }else {
        CellInfoWcdma cellinfogsm = (CellInfoWcdma) telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
        CellSignalStrength cellSignalStrengthGsm = cellinfogsm.getCellSignalStrength();
        return cellSignalStrengthGsm.getLevel() > 0;
    }
}
```